# Upgrading a SQL Server 2008R2 failover cluster to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, cluster-computing, upgrade

I tried to upgrade a failover cluster running SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2012 but the upgrade wizard reported a rule failure:

"The SQL Server and Analysis Services features of the selected clustered SQL Server 2005 instance have been installed into separate groups. SQL Server 2012 setup can only upgrade clustered instances installed in a single group. To continue, uninstall either SQL Server or Analysis Services before you upgrade."

Apart from the fact that the current cluster is running SQL Server 2008R2 (it wasn't even upgraded from 2005) both SQL Server and Analysis Services are in the same cluster resource group. The advice to uninstall one or the other is also unhelpful because adding/removing features on a failover cluster is not supported (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547273).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Graham

Comment: I found a KB article http://http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955784 which has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you slipstreamed all the latest service packs into the 2012 installer media?

If you're using RTM media there are loads of bugs in the setup program, good news is that this is now much easier to do in 2012 than it was in 2008:

[Product Updates in SQL Server 2012 Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231670.aspx)

Comment: The setup wizard installs the latest updates and I am using the SP1 media. Still no luck.